# Add 'active' class dynamically on foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I want to add `active` class whenever I click on any 'li' of the table. 
Statically i have successfully added 'active' class but now I want to add class dynamically using foreach loop.

**Blade.php**

```
   @foreach($data as $key=>$item)
        <div class="roles-menu">
            <ul class="nav" id="item_id" onclick="item()">
                            <li id="active" onclick="makeactive()" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getID('{{ $item->id }}')">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <input hidden id="input" value="{{ $item->id }}">
        </div>

    @endforeach
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    function makeactive(){
        $('li a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: all selectors need a correct scope (parent/closest) also change ID to data attributes this will correctly fetch all elements.

Comment: $(this).closest('ul').find('a.active').removeClass..

Comment: `$("#input").each` this would mean that you have multiple elements with the same ID, An Id should always be unique

Comment: Well there are multiple elements and they have unique ids but I am not using that for adding or removing active class

Comment: @Faiez how can they have unique id's if you use this line inside your foreach `<input hidden id="input" value="{{ $item->id }}">`

Comment: Do input field will effect the active class because I want 'active' class in li  and I am using input field to give 'id' to another using form which I have not shown here.

Comment: If the input fields with dubious duplicate IDs are not relevant to the question, then please remove them from the question!  See [mcve] for more info regarding *minimal* code.

Comment: Are you adding new `li` and `a` elements *after* you have called your js script?  (ie adding elements dynamically) or just want the code to work for existing/created on startup elements?

Comment: You're mixing `onclick=` with js events and jquery selectors with js selecting - you'll find it easier if you stick with just one.

Comment: It's hard to tell (from the pre-edit) if the `function getID(val)` returns false / preventsdefault and stops the jquery event from firing.

Comment: @ПавелИванов replacement above for `$('a').removeClass('active');` should fix your issue, if it's not working then try to remove parts eg (both `onclick=`) until it does work, then try to find why those parts are causing your issue.

Comment: Well I am getting elements from the database. Actually I was trying to give element_id and remove and add class from one click.

Comment: Please check new updated code still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but I have done using simple classes. And looks like the problem was on the 'onclick'

```
            @foreach($data as $key=>$item)
            <div id="roles" class="roles-menu">
                <ul class="nav" id="item_id" onclick="item()">
                    <li id="active" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getID('{{ $item->id }}')">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>

                </ul>
                <input hidden id="input" value="{{ $item->id }}">
            </div>

            @endforeach

<script>
        $("#item_id li a").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that would be using `event delegation` instead of `for-loop`. That way you can add event to the parent and all the children will be able to trigger that event even when you add them dynamically (later). I am using for loop here to clear active class from the currently active item before setting a new item to active.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');

list.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target !== list) {
    const items = list.childNodes;

    // remove current active class
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      // check if the node is not a text node
      if (items[i].nodeType !== 3) {
        items[i].className = '';
      }
    }
    event.target.className = 'active';
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Faiez lost one letter during formatting, should be ok now.

Comment: @Faiez What exact error are you getting? As you can see for yourself that it is working here, therefore there must be error in your code. Check if `query selector` is getting the right thing.

Comment: If it's not working then try to remove parts eg (both `onclick=`) until it does work, then try to find why those parts are causing your issue.